# RazorViewEngine and Unit Test

Tags: unit-testing, razor, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm writing a custom RazorViewEngine for ASP.NET MVC 4 and I'm having a hard time to Unit Test it because the base class is calling to things that go up to the BuildManager and the VirtualPathProvider which throw all kind of exceptions, so within every new test I made, I needed to stub out something else because the underlying mechanism is making calls to objects that I haven't stubbed and throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

So what I did was writing an interface similar to this one that allows me to wrap the calls to the base class of the engine.

```
internal interface IViewEngineDelegate
{
    Func<ControllerContext, string, IView> CreatePartialView { get; set; }

    Func<ControllerContext, string, string, IView> CreateView { get; set; }

    Func<ControllerContext, string, bool> FileExists { get; set; }

    Func<ControllerContext, string, bool, ViewEngineResult> FindPartialView { get; set; }

    Func<ControllerContext, string, string, bool, ViewEngineResult> FindView { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I can do the following thing in my production code.

```
public class CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    private readonly IViewEngineDelegate _viewEngineDelegate;

    public CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine()
    {
        _viewEngineDelegate = new ViewEngineDelegate
        {
            CreatePartialView = base.CreatePartialView, 
            CreateView = base.CreateView, 
            FileExists = base.FileExists, 
            FindPartialView = base.FindPartialView, 
            FindView = base.FindView
        };
    }

    internal CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine(IViewEngineDelegate viewEngineDelegate)
    {
        _viewEngineDelegate = viewEngineDelegate;
    }

    protected override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        // TODO: Do something.

        return _viewEngineDelegate.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath)
    }
}
```

Finally, I can test it by stubbing out the calls, like this.

```
ViewEngineDelegate engineDelegate = new ViewEngineDelegate
{
    CreatePartialView = (controllerContext, partialPath) => FakeViewFactory.Instance.Create(controllerContext, partialPath),
};

CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine engine = new CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine(engineDelegate);
```

After some thinking I thought of just doing this because I think that I over-engineered the design, so I've decided to go with a more straightforward approach.

```
public class CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    protected sealed override IView CreatePartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        // TODO: Do something.

        return default(IView);
    }

    protected virtual IView CreatePartialViewCore(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialPath)
    {
        return base.CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialPath);
    }
}
```

I'm not really satisfied with either one of these approaches and that's the reason I'm posting about it, I wonder whether there's a better way of doing that or well, maybe it's just me and these are acceptable/reasonable approaches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally made it using the following approach.

This is a sample of the ViewEngine I wanted to test.

```
public class CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine : RazorViewEngine
{
    protected override IView CreateView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewPath, string masterPath)
    {
        viewPath = GetViewPath(controllerContext, viewPath);

        masterPath = GetViewPath(controllerContext, masterPath);

        return base.CreateView(controllerContext, viewPath, masterPath);
    }

    private static string GetAssemblyName(ControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(controllerContext.Controller.GetType().Assembly.Location);
    }

    private static string GetViewPath(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
    {
        string asmName = GetAssemblyName(controllerContext);

        return virtualPath.Replace("%Assembly%", asmName);
    }
}
```

I'm using factories for most of my tests to create my objects (generally, for complex objects) so this is the factory that responsible to create the ViewEngine which uses a Shunt (see the 'Self-Shunt' testing pattern for more info).

```
public sealed class CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineFactory : SingleFactory<CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineFactory>
{
    public CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine Create(bool fileExists)
    {
        return new CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineShunt(fileExists);
    }

    private class CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineShunt : CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine
    {
        private readonly bool _fileExists;

        private readonly IViewEngine _viewEngine;

        public CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineShunt(bool fileExists)
        {
            _fileExists = fileExists;

            _viewEngine = FakeViewEngineFactory.Instance.Create();
        }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string viewName, string masterName, bool useCache)
        {
            IView view = CreateView(controllerContext, viewName, masterName);

            return new ViewEngineResult(view, _viewEngine);
        }

        public override ViewEngineResult FindPartialView(ControllerContext controllerContext, string partialViewName, bool useCache)
        {
            IView view = CreatePartialView(controllerContext, partialViewName);

            return new ViewEngineResult(view, _viewEngine);
        }

        protected override bool FileExists(ControllerContext controllerContext, string virtualPath)
        {
            return _fileExists;
        }
    }
}
```

Here are the actual tests I made for the ViewEngine.

```
internal class CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineTests
{
    public class FindView
    {
        [Theory,
         InlineData("~/%Assembly%/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Lynx.Tests.Framework.Web.Mvc/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml"),
         InlineData("~/%Assembly%/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml", "~/Lynx.Tests.Framework.Web.Mvc/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml")]
        public void Should_prefix_the_virtual_path_with_the_assembly_name_for_normal_views(string viewPath, string expectedViewPath)
        {
            // Arrange
            const bool FILE_EXISTS = true;

            CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine engine = CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineFactory.Instance.Create(FILE_EXISTS);

            ControllerBase controller = new ControllerStub();

            ControllerContext controllerContext = FakeControllerContextFactory.Instance.Create(controller);

            // Act
            ViewEngineResult result = engine.FindView(controllerContext, viewPath, string.Empty, false);

            RazorView razorView = (RazorView)result.View;

            string actualViewPath = razorView.ViewPath;

            // Assert
            actualViewPath.Should().Be(expectedViewPath);
        }

        [Theory,
         InlineData(@"Views\DummyView.cshtml", "~/%Assembly%/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Lynx.Tests.Framework.Web.Mvc/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml"),
         InlineData(@"Views\DummyView.cshtml", "~/%Assembly%/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml", "~/Lynx.Tests.Framework.Web.Mvc/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml")]
        public void Should_prefix_the_virtual_path_with_the_assembly_name_for_layout(string viewPath, string layoutPath, string expectedLayoutPath)
        {
            // Arrange
            const bool FILE_EXISTS = true;

            CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngine engine = CsEmbeddedRazorViewEngineFactory.Instance.Create(FILE_EXISTS);

            ControllerBase controller = new ControllerStub();

            ControllerContext controllerContext = FakeControllerContextFactory.Instance.Create(controller);

            // Act
            ViewEngineResult result = engine.FindView(controllerContext, viewPath, layoutPath, false);

            RazorView razorView = (RazorView)result.View;

            string actualLayoutPath = razorView.LayoutPath;

            // Assert
            actualLayoutPath.Should().Be(expectedLayoutPath);
        }
    }

    private class ControllerStub : ControllerBase
    {
        protected override void ExecuteCore()
        {
        }
    }
}
```